# Is this how to redirect all subpages of a subdomain with regex?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I believe this is correct. Can someone verify this for me or create the modifications that are needed?

I want to redirect "www.example.org/blogs" to "www.example.org/blog" while handling all the subpages such as "www.example.org/blogs/article-here"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*)$ http://www.example.org/blog/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I say .com and .org but my interest is in a .org domain.

Comment: If you make an error in your question, don't just mention that in a comment: [edit] the question.

Comment: Thanks TRiG for the tip.

Comment: looks good to me although you may want to restrict your path to certain characters, as `.` matches everything but `\n`.

Comment: @tenub Can you show me inside the code please?

Comment: `^blogs/(.*)$` -> `^blogs/([\w0-9/~-]*)$` would allow all alphanumeric chars as well as `_`, `/`, `~`, and `-`. There may be others you'd want to allow or disallow though.